# How to connect to ASP.NET Core server from another application using HTTP CONNECT?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, tunnel

### Scenario

My goal is to make a custom web server which acts similar to how Visual Studios devtunnels work, merely as a learning and understanding project because prior to devtunnels i have always wondered how reverse http tunneling works exactly.

### My issue

The breakpoint in the if block of the server middleware is never hit.

### Code

This is my client code of a Console program, which i would be running locally:

```cs
    internal class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var tunnelClient = new TunnelClient("https://localhost:7236");
            await tunnelClient.ConnectAsync(CancellationToken.None);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Tunnel Client running.");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.Write(".");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.Write(".");
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Console.Clear();
            }
        }
    }

    public class TunnelClient : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Uri _address;
        private TcpClient? _client;

        public TunnelClient(string address)
        {
            _address = new Uri(address);
        }

        public async Task<bool> ConnectAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            if (_client is not null)
                return true;
            try
            {
                _client = await ConnectClientAsync();

                var message = $"CONNECT {_address.Authority} HTTP/1.1\r\n";
                await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);

                await _client.GetStream().WriteAsync(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message), cancellationToken);

                return true;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                throw;
            }
        }

        private async Task<TcpClient> ConnectClientAsync()
        {
            switch (_address.Host)
            {
                case "localhost":
                    var client = new TcpClient();
                    await client.ConnectAsync("localhost", _address.Port);
                    return client;
                default:
                    throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This is effectively the relevant parts of the ASP.NET Core server (which in theory would run accessible through the internet):

```cs
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace BackEnd.Tunneling;

public class TunnelMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public TunnelMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Method == "CONNECT")
        {
            // this breakpoint is never hit
        }
        else
        {
            var r = context.Request;
            // Pass non-CONNECT requests to the next middleware
            await _next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

My server intialization code:

[image: Server Program.cs]

Comment: Have you checked your request context details? What ar you getting in context.Request.Method?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron No. I never get any request with the CONNECT as method

Comment: Thanks for your response,  I want to know if set debugger in  `TunnelMiddleware` does it hit or even does `TunnelClient` ever executed?

Comment: Yeah. TunnelClient does execute, just never the HTTP Connect. As if there is something wrong with the request

Comment: As per your snippet I cannot see any reference of `TunnelClient` so wondering how it should called or execute that.